# Php mysql emoji double character

Tags: php, mysql, ios, emoji

I've been working perfectly on my local mysql server with emoji icons saving strings as
**\ud83d\ude03\ud83d\ude03\ud83d\ude03** (for 3 happyfaces)

But I just moved to a 1and1 phpmysql server, upload the same database with the same php scripts and every time I insert a new 'row'  it duplicates de \ bar so it looks like :
**\\ud83d\\ude2c** (with double \ in every \ char)

What's wrong? I could easyly replace all \ by \ but just wanna understand why this is happening and how to fixit in a cleanway!

Thanks!

Comment: Something is escaping the \ bar.

Answer (score 0):

Your new server has [magic quotes enabled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php).

This can either be fixed by disabling magic quotes, or a better solution is to find a more competent hosting company that doesn't have this bad feature enabled by default.